# Javascript point to point angle calculation

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, geometry, angle

We got 3 points: **start**, **end** and **mail**.

[image: description]

The mail image, moves in a curved line from the start and end point, this is done by jQuery animate.

Now the next step is to make the mail image rotate while the animation is running. So at the start point and end point it would be rotated 0 degrees, but while animating, it should rotate facing the path of the animation. (see the image)

What I have tried:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5dRd/6/)

```
// Init dom elements
var $start = $('#start');
var $end = $('#end');
var $mail = $('#mail');

// Get position coordinates
var startPos = $start.position();
var endPos = $end.Position();

// Angle calculation
var getAngle = function(currX, currY, endX, endY) {
  var angle = Math.atan2(currX - endX, currY - endY) * (180 / Math.PI);

  if (angle < 0) {
    angle = Math.abs(angle);
  } else {
    angle = 360 - angle;
  }

  return angle;
};

// Mail angle
var getMailAngle = function() {
  var currPos = $mail.position();
  var endPos = $end.position();
  return getAngle(currPos.left, currPos.top, endPos.left, endPos.top);
};

// Animate
$mail.animate({top: endPos.top, left: endPos.left}, {
  specialEasing: {left: "easeInSine", top: "linear"},

  // Executed each "animation" frame, so we rotate here.
  step: function() {
    var angle = getMailAngle();
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg'));
  }
});
```

But the code above is not correct, the angle doesn't face up when started / ended, I have very little experience with geometry math, so I really appreciate help for the rotating calculations.

Comment: I don't see why it should face up when started/ended given that the path pictured does not exit the start and enter the end at a 90° angle.

Comment: @MattBall the true animation does actually start and end with 90° angle, the image was quickly in photoshop and has an offset sadly

Comment: Is this what you see? http://jsfiddle.net/R5dRd/

Comment: A JSFiddle would help to see what's going wrong. The difference between the y coordinates should be the first argument to `Math.atan2`. Also, it looks like you're calculating the angle based on the slope of the line connecting the current position with the end position (a secant). Really, what you want is something that approximates the local slope of the animation curve (a tangent). A reasonable way to get this would be to do the `atan2` between the current position and the position at the previous step.

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks for jsfiddle, it is exactly what is going on, at the last few steps of the animation it seems to twist weird and stuff, I'll add the jsfiddle to my question with a longer animation duration so you can see what is going on exactly.

Comment: @acjohnson55 updated my question with jsfiddle, I'm going to experiment right away thanks!

Comment: @randomKek Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/acjohnson55/RV6ZQ/10/. It's not a full solution, but it might be a decent start. I found that I couldn't just use the previous position, because position is reported in pixels, and often, the step would only be one pixel, producing really jagged rotation. Instead, I tried using a delay line of old positions, and calculate the angle based on where the item was 5 steps ago, to smooth it out. It's being weird though, so there's probably some sort of error, but maybe you'll find it helpful.

Comment: Looking at what's happening, it appears that getting the current position is not producing stable results, because the rotation is effecting the position coordinates. You'll have to find a way to compensate for this. Wish I could help more, but I gotta get back to solving my own problems :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you need to use an easing animation that starts and ends with the same "angle". If you look at the different [easing options](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html), `swing`, `easeInOutQuad` and `easeInOutSine` are some of the valid options.

To calculate an approximation of the angle, you can look at the mail icon's current position and its next position (in the next animation frame). To get a good approximation you need to "manually" calculate the current and next position using the easing function. This also means you need to control the animation manually.

Here's a code snippet, and you can also see it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjVHW/10/).

```
// Init dom elements
var $start = $('#start');
var $end = $('#end');
var $mail = $('#mail');

// Get position coordinates
var startPos = $start.offset();
var endPos = $end.offset();

// Angle calculation
var getAngle = function(currX, currY, endX, endY) {
  var angle = Math.atan2(currX - endX, currY - endY) * (180 / Math.PI);

  if (angle < 0) {
    angle = Math.abs(angle);
  } else {
    angle = 360 - angle;
  }

  return angle;
};

// Animate
var maxframe = 1000;
$({frame: 0}).animate({frame: maxframe}, {
    easing: "linear",
    duration: 1000,

  // Executed each "animation" frame, so we rotate here.
  step: function() {
      var easing = $.easing.easeInOutQuad;
      var left = easing(0, this.frame, startPos.left, endPos.left - startPos.left, maxframe);
      var leftNext = easing(0, this.frame+1, startPos.left, endPos.left - startPos.left, maxframe);

      var top = startPos.top + (endPos.top - startPos.top) * this.frame / maxframe;
      var topNext = startPos.top + (endPos.top - startPos.top) * (this.frame + 1) / maxframe;

      var angle = getAngle(left, top, leftNext, topNext);     
      $mail.offset({left: left, top: top});
      $mail.css('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
  },

  // Set the final position
  complete: function() {
      $mail.offset($end.offset());
      $mail.css('transform', ''); 
  }  
});
```

Comment: These formulas will cause the mail icon to always try and point directly towards the final point, not necessarily tangent to its current path.

Comment: Hi Seth. No, it doesn't always point towards the final point. You can see this by making a more complex easing function. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mn88E/1/).

Comment: You are right. I thought your code snippet was the same as what was mentioned earlier (which does always point at the final point). This works perfectly on JSFiddle.